# Writing to a File in C?

Tags: c, file, io

I want to write a string to `FILE` using memory allocation and I want stream accept  input as many as user  wants. In order to do that, array of character gets bigger and bigger until the user press<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.

But my code doesn't work properly and I don't know why!

Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(void)
 {
   size_t index=0, newsize=0;//are used for reallocating
   int ctrl=1;//Primary value for CTRL for going through while loop
   char *sentence , singlechar;
    sentence=(char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("E:\\Textsample.txt","w");
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
        free(fptr);
        puts("Error occurs when trying to allocate memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    singlechar=getchar();
    sentence[index]=singlechar;

    while((ctrl=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
            /**Making sentence bigger**/
            newsize++;
            realloc(sentence,newsize);
            if(sentence==NULL)
            {
                free(sentence);
                puts("Error occurs when trying to reallocate memory.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            /**Putting inputed character into sentence**/
            index++;
            singlechar=(char) ctrl;

            /*Check if it is EOF*/
            if((int) ctrl==EOF)
            {
                free(sentence);
                puts("EOF Reached.");
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else
            {
                sentence[index]=singlechar;
                fwrite(sentence,sizeof sentence[0],newsize,fptr);
            }
      }

        free(fptr);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: You don't `free` file pointers. Especially if they are NULL. You really need to read some documentation of the functions you are trying to use, like `realloc`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have freed. Where are you mentioning?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are facing? What goes wrong in which way? What is the desired behaviour and is that different from what you get?

Comment: I am saying - you should *not*

Comment: `free(fptr);` --> `free(sentence);`

Comment: @Yunnosch_I want to write sentences to a text and when I press Ctrl+Z it finishes with writing.

Comment: `realloc(sentence,1);` : The size is not changed. Also, the return value is discarded.

Comment: Use `getline` if available

Comment: `free(fptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;` --> `fclose(fptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Would you please correct my problems in an answer?

Comment: I am not enthusiastic.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Beyond the reasons already stated (improper use of `realloc` and `free`-ing something not dynamically allocated (a `FILE*`) ). All you seem to be trying to do is store whatever is typed in to an output file. You don't need an array for that whatsoever; just a single `char`, an open `FILE*` to your output file, and `fputc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here is erroneous. The method you came up with is a huge waste of CPU and memory alloc / realloc. The problem here is `realloc(sentence, 1);`. This call is an `O(n)` linear copy of the source bytes. Adding bytes one by one each time you type in some character makes your total allocation process `O(n^2)` which is **way worse**.

What prevents me with your technique to just keep typing and run your system out of memory ?

Moreover, it is best practice to allocate a base array (say 128 bytes?) and make it grow exponentially.

Oh and, one does not cast the result of a `malloc` call. It is quite ugly code and useless.

I would suggest something like

```
size_t BUF_SIZE = 128;
size_t BUF_GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
size_t MAX_BUF_SIZE = 1024; // Prevent too large memory allocation  
char *text = malloc(BUF_SIZE * sizeof char);

// Do your input here...

// When you run out of space:
if (BUF_SIZE * BUF_GROWTH_FACTOR <= MAX_BUF_SIZE)
    text = realloc(text, BUF_SIZE * BUF_GROWTH_FACTOR);
else
   // Handle the error
```

Comment: Oh and by the way, `realloc(sentence, 1)` **doesn't grow** the memory space by one, but **sets** it to one. That is, with algorithm, you never *extend* your memory allocated to the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now (apart from calling free on NULL pointers and file descriptors - don't do any of those) is read the input character by character, store it in an array (which you resize each time to size 1 - I guess you meant index + 1 there, which is still extremely inefficient) and write the first character ever read to file.

I didn't run the code but I see at least 3 points at which it will SEGFAULT, all mentioned above.

What you WANT to do instead, is read the input to a buffer (an array of an arbitrary size, no need to resize it at all in this case), and as soon as the buffer is full OR you hit EOF - write to file and reset index to 0.

Comment: Passing a null pointe to `free` is not a problem as such.